# Creating query to reference prior row over grouped list of users

Tags: t-sql

We have a collection of users with duplicates, and I'm writing a process to merge them.  Basically selecting out all users with matching names and DOB's, then I need a list of user id's to merge them together. Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpUsers (UserID Integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, FullName NVARCHAR(50), Birthdate DATE);

INSERT INTO #tmpUsers (UserID, FullName, Birthdate)
VALUES
(120,'John Michael','1985-03-02'),
(45,'John Michael','1985-03-02'),
(60,'John Michael','1985-03-02'),
(33,'John Michael','1985-03-02'),
(12,'Tim Smith','1973-01-02'),
(16,'Tim Smith','1973-01-02'),
(29,'Jane Thomas','1990-06-20'),
(43,'Jane Thomas','1990-06-20'),
(8,'Jane Thomas','1990-06-20');
```

The process I'm building needs to have a new table ordered by the Fullname and DOB, but have the current and prior ID so it can merge together, like this:

| Name | DOB | Merge From | Merge To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane Thomas | 1990-06-20 | 8 | 29 |
| Jane Thomas | 1990-06-20 | 29 | 43 |
| John Michael | 1985-03-02 | 33 | 45 |
| John Michael | 1985-03-02 | 45 | 60 |
| John Michael | 1985-03-02 | 60 | 120 |
| Tim Smith | 1973-01-02 | 12 | 16 |

The process basically merges or collapses the oldest values into the newest one, so in the end we will only have one User for each.  I'm just unable to find any good way to do this, though I'm sure there's a simple TSQL method. I hoped someone had advise on how to build it.

In the end after my process runs it'll have three users with ID's 16, 43, 120.  The others will either be removed or deactivated, but just getting the query to start the process is where I'm hung.

Thanks.

Comment: For jane: why don't both records just show merge to 43?  or john going to 120?  Why the middle step?  Put another way: why 8 to 29 for Jane.  and why not 8 to 43?  why does it have go to through 29?  All Original 8's have to get touched twice which seems inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT FullName as Name, BirthDate as DOB, UserID as [Merge From],
       LEAD(UserID) OVER(PARTITION BY fullname, birthdate 
                         ORDER BY fullname, birthdate, userid) as [Merge To]
    from #tmpUsers
) t 
WHERE [Merge To] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Name, DOB, [Merge From];
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c2557bc038cab44ab000a1b35ab1563b

Answer (score 0):

This is ubiquitously solved with `row_number` to select the max value per group:

```
with u as (
    select UserId, FullName, BirthDate,
        Row_Number() over(partition by FullName order by UserId desc) keepMe
    from #tmpUsers
)
select UserId, FullName, BirthDate
from u
where KeepMe=1
```

Comment: It looks like they want more than one value per person... more like a transaction record

Comment: I interpreted the question from the final paragraph as the OP wanting to end up with just the deduped rows based on the Id, possibly I misread, hopefully the OP can clarify

Comment: I read that three records is the end goal, but there will be other related tables with data that needs to be handled, so he wants this intermediate step first.

Answer (score 0):

Though my suggestion follows a different approach to solve the underlying problem, why not run this simple query,

```
SELECT
  MIN(UserID) AS MergeFrom,
  MAX(UserID) AS MergeTo,
  FullName,
  BirthDate
FROM #tmpusers
GROUP BY 
  FullName,
  BirthDate
HAVING MIN(UserID)<>MAX(UserID)
```

shift users as indicated and do this in a loop until the query returns an empty result set?

Comment: He wants more than one record per person.

Comment: Yes, true but the underlying problem can easily be solved as explained.